# MS Access form -> Combox used to filter other combobox results

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown combo box in a form for a `"Project_ID"` called: `Combo28` (this is the primary key basically). There are also 5 other `"Error_Code"` combo boxes called: `cboErrCod1, cboErrCod2, cboErrCod3, cboErrCod4, cboErrCod5.`

I'm looking to create some sort of "On Change" code that will only display the Error Codes pertaining to the Project_ID selected in the Combo box `"Combo28"` only.

The error codes are stored in a separate table and each code is associate to a particular `project_Id.`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have exactly five error code comboboxes. To do this easily and let access do all the work for you, you could either:

A: Have a parent form containing the dropdown for project_ID. Create a subform (continuous form view). Set the recordsource to your error codes and `Link to Master using Project_ID`

B: Create a subform with the recordsource `"Select ErrorCodes from yourTable WHERE Project_ID = [Forms]![yourForm]![combo28]`  Where combo28 is your project_ID. In the after update event for your combobox, call `.requery` and perhaps `.refresh` on your subform.

Comment: is there a way to do this without using a subform?